# How to upload really large datasets to an hdf5 file?

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "populate_h5.py", line 116, in <module>
    dset_X[n_images:n_images+1,:,:,:]=hc
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper (-------src-dir--------/h5py/_objects.c:2582)
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper (-------src-dir--------/h5py/_objects.c:2541)
  File "/Users/alex/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/_hl/dataset.py", line 618, in __setitem__
    self.id.write(mspace, fspace, val, mtype, dxpl=self._dxpl)
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper (-------src-dir--------/h5py/_objects.c:2582)
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper (-------src-dir--------/h5py/_objects.c:2541)
  File "h5py/h5d.pyx", line 221, in h5py.h5d.DatasetID.write (-------src-dir--------/h5py/h5d.c:3421)
  File "h5py/_proxy.pyx", line 132, in h5py._proxy.dset_rw (-------src-dir--------/h5py/_proxy.c:1794)
  File "h5py/_proxy.pyx", line 93, in h5py._proxy.H5PY_H5Dwrite (-------src-dir--------/h5py/_proxy.c:1501)
IOError: Can't prepare for writing data (File write failed: time = sat jun 11 13:31:12 2016
, filename = 'raw_tensors.h5', file descriptor = 3, errno = 28, error message = 'no space left on device', buf = 0x20b9b5658, total write size = 42288, bytes this sub-write = 42288, bytes actually written = 18446744073709551615, offset = 184442875904)
Exception IOError: IOError("Driver write request failed (File write failed: time = sat jun 11 13:31:12 2016\n, filename = 'raw_tensors.h5', file descriptor = 3, errno = 28, error message = 'no space left on device', buf = 0x20c404a08, total write size = 50176, bytes this sub-write = 50176, bytes actually written = 18446744073709551615, offset = 184442918192)",) in 'h5py._objects.ObjectID.__dealloc__' ignored
Exception IOError: IOError("Driver write request failed (File write failed: time = sat jun 11 13:31:12 2016\n, filename = 'raw_tensors.h5', file descriptor = 3, errno = 28, error message = 'no space left on device', buf = 0x20b9bfc08, total write size = 94080, bytes this sub-write = 94080, bytes actually written = 18446744073709551615, offset = 184443921712)",) in 'h5py._objects.ObjectID.__dealloc__' ignored
Segmentation fault: 11
```

This is the generator:

```
files = glob.glob('../manga-resized/sliced_images/*.png')
f = h5py.File('raw_tensors.h5','w')
dset_X = f.create_dataset('X',(1,960,224,224),maxshape=(None,960,224,224),chunks=True)
dset_y = f.create_dataset('y',(1,112,224*224),maxshape=(None,112,224*224),chunks=True)

n_images = 0
for fl in files[:1000]:
    img = color.rgb2lab(io.imread(fl)[..., :3])
    X = img[:,:,:1]
    y = img[:,:,1:]
    print "y shape: ",y.shape
    print "X shape: ",X.shape
    X_rows,X_columns,X_channels=X.shape
    y_rows,y_columns,y_channels=y.shape
    X_chunk = np.transpose(X,(2,0,1))
    X_chunk_3d = np.tile(X_chunk,(3,1,1))
    print "X_chunk_3d: ",X_chunk_3d.shape
    X_chunk_4d = np.expand_dims(X_chunk_3d,axis=0)
    print "X_chunk_4d: ",X_chunk_4d.shape
    hc = extract_hypercolumn(model,[3,8,15,22],X_chunk_4d)
    y_chunk = np.reshape(y,(y_rows*y_columns,y_channels))
    classed = KNN.predict_proba(y_chunk)
    classed = np.transpose(classed,(1,0))
    dset_X.resize(n_images+1,axis=0)
    dset_y.resize(n_images+1,axis=0)
    print "X_chunk: ",X_chunk.shape,"dset_X: ",dset_X.shape
    print "hypercolumn shape: ",hc.shape
    print "y_chunk: ",classed.shape,"dset_y: ",dset_y.shape
    dset_X[n_images:n_images+1,:,:,:]=hc
    dset_y[n_images:n_images+1,:,:]=classed
    n_images+= 1
    print dset_X.shape
    print dset_y.shape

f.close()
```

There are 1836 files in files, but as you can see we are only using 1000 of them. The error happens on the 857th iteration.

The error message: no space left on device is somewhat clear but Im not sure how to remedy this? Do I need to create a separate hdf5 file for every 500 files for instance?

Comment: The maximum chunk size of a dataset in HDF5 is 4GB, and the maximum dataset size is something like 16 exabytes, so I doubt that you're hitting the  upper limit for hdf5 files. "No space left on device" might refer to the disk you're saving `raw_tensors.h5` on however. I'm more worried about this in the error message: `bytes actually written = 18446744073709551615`. This is about 18.5 exabytes, which suggests something has gone badly wrong.

Comment: Is it possible that `y_chunk = np.reshape(y,(y_rows*y_columns,y_channels))` should be `y_chunk = np.reshape(y,(y_channels, y_rows*y_columns))`?

Comment: @Yossarian `bytes actually written = 18446744073709551615` probably just refers to a return value of `-1` for the POSIX routine write (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) which is cast to double and back which would produce this value. It just means what it says: Your HD is full. You can't write anymore.